# Why does this program work fine on my computer, but cause an overflow on another computer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm teaching a friend C. We were working with structs and pointers and I gave him a program to try out on his computer. We were going to deconstruct the program line by line so he could understand how structs and pointers worked together. On my end, I get this result:

> Value of a in astr is 5
>   Value of b in astr is 5.550000
>   Value of c in astr is 77
>   Value of d in astr is 888.888800

On his computer, the program mostly worked except for the last value of astr->d which printed out some very large negative number. So my question is, why does this happen on his computer, but work fine on mine? below is the offending code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    struct a_struct{
        int a;
        float b;
        int c;
        double d;
    };

    struct a_struct* astr;

    astr = (struct a_struct*)malloc(sizeof(astr));

    astr->a = 5;
    astr->b = 5.55;
    astr->c = 77;
    astr->d = 888.8888;

    printf("Value of a in astr is %d\n", astr->a);
    printf("Value of b in astr is %f\n", astr->b);
    printf("Value of c in astr is %d\n", astr->c);
    printf("Value of d in astr is %lf\n", astr->d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because of "*Undefined Behaviour*".

Comment: I think your `sizeof` is incorrect. I would recommend this:                               `astr = (struct a_struct*)malloc(sizeof(struct a_struct));`

Comment: No, `astr = malloc (sizeof *astr);` See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) for thorough explanation.

Comment: Please don't try teaching C if you are not good at it yourself.

Comment: God forbid I make a mistake. I'm human. And they say that you learn more as a teacher, than as a student. I'm not a professional programmer, I know. I program as a hobby.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have at least two problems.

First, your `malloc` call is incorrect.

```
astr = (struct a_struct*)malloc(sizeof(astr));
```

`astr` is a pointer, so `sizeof(astr)` is the size of a pointer. You want to allocate enough memory to hold an object of type `struct astruct`.

```
astr = (struct a_struct*)malloc(sizeof (struct a_struct)));
```

Or, more simply and robustly:

```
astr = malloc(sizeof *astr);
```

(The argument to `sizeof` is not evaluated, so `sizeof *astr` gives you the size of what `astr` points to without trying to dereference it. The cast is unnecessary because `malloc` returns a `void*`, which is implicitly converted to the required pointer type.)

Second, you're using <strike>the wrong format</strike> not quite the right format to print `astr->d`. The `%f` format works for both `float` and `double` arguments (because `float` arguments to `printf` are promoted to `double`). The correct format for a `long double` argument is `%Lf`.  Just use `%f` for both `astr->b` and `astr->d`. (Starting with C99 `"%lf"` is equivalent to `%f`, but it's better just to use `%f'`.)

Third (ok, I miscounted), you should check whether the `malloc` call succeeded by comparing the result to `NULL`. It's not *likely* to fail for such a small allocation, but it's a very good habit to check consistently. If it fails, you can just abort the program with an error message (for larger programs some more sophisticated error handling might be called for).

Comment: I can't upvote again, but unconciously I tried to, because of "*Third*".

Comment: Your second position is not an issue actually, because of standard promotions. The "ell" is just redundant.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Yeah, I definitely should have done "sizeof struct a_struct" instead. I normally would have done that but hey, everyone makes mistakes.

Comment: @Olaf: The `%lf` format is ok in C99 and later -- not because of standard promotions, but because the standard says that `l` has no effect on a following `f` conversion. In C90, that rule didn't exist, so the behavior was undefined. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @NiaKitty: Writing `astr = malloc(sizeof *astr);` is more robust than mentioning the type explicitly. You don't have to update it if the type that `astr` points to changes. `astr = malloc(sizeof (struct a_struct));` is perfectly valid, but too easy to break as the code is maintained.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Sorry, I was unclear. `%f` works because of the standard arithmetic promotions `float` to `double`. This is an asymmetry to `scanf`. `%lf` for `double`, to makes that identical to `scanf`. Whether one uses `%f` or `%lf` is a personal decission and makes not really a difference. And the C tag implies standard C, so both are correct. Not sure where you see a `long double` argument, though.

Comment: @NiaKitty: Please read the standard (or a good book). If using with types, you need the function-form of `sizeof`.

Comment: @Olaf: I incorrectly wrote `sizeof struct a_strict` in my answer, so that's my fault. I later corrected it to add the parentheses. (A compiler would catch the missing parens *very* quickly). BTW, `sizeof (` *type-name* `)` is not "the function-form". The parentheses do not correspond to the parentheses in a function call. They're just part of the syntax of `sizeof`.)

Comment: @Olaf: `%lf` was added in C99, a change that made existing incorrect code valid. Using `%f` makes your code potentially portable even to older implementations.

Comment: @KeithThompson: C99 has some subtle incompatibilities (resp. more exactly defined behaviour), so portability can be more of a problem anyway. In general, I strongly support moving away from ancient C90. It is just a burden and should be burried deep. It definitively **is** a matter of personal preference. As I don't use this part of the stdlib anyway in my project, I actually don't care much.

Comment: @Olaf: Using `"%f"` for `float` and `double` arguments to `printf` is perfectly portable. C99 did add permission to use `"%lf"`, but there's no particular reason to take advantage of it.

Comment: Even before C99, `%lf` was a very common non-standard extension that most compilers supported.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the program is allocating memory incorrectly. The below statement actually assign memory equal to the size of the pointer, which could be 32 bit or 64 bit depending on the OS architecture.

```
struct a_struct* astr;
astr = (struct a_struct*)malloc(sizeof(astr));
```

Instead you should do:

```
struct a_struct* astr;
astr = (struct a_struct*)malloc(sizeof(struct a_struct));
```

Comment: Looks like George Bou and I both were typing the same answer at the same time. George beat me by 35 seconds. :)

Comment: Honestly I don't like your answer, it's correct nevertheless so downvoting is not necessary.

Comment: But you provided a more detailed answer. Well done! :)

Comment: iharob, agree that it is not as good and complete as the answer provided by Keith.

Answer (score 0):

If you allocate memory dynamically you should take care to allocate memory for the object to hold your data, not only a pointer to the first member of something you haven't allocated.  "The other way around" would be to explicitly declare the struct as variable first, and then the pointer to point at its address:

```
struct a_struct astrV;
struct a_struct *astr = &astrV;
```